# Enable PoE on Cisco non-PoE switches

Tags: cisco, switch, power-over-ethernet

I would like to know whether is there any option to convert the non-PoE switches, Cisco 2960X-48TS-L and Cisco 2960X-24TS-L, to PoE Switches.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot convert switches so they become POE.

But you can use special devices that are called "POE Injectors" in addition to the switch.

They exist in 24 and 48 ports (and other size) versions.